# How to get 30 most recent results from multiples userIDs

Tags: sql

I'm trying to input a set of userIDs to output one variable from multiple userIDs but only the most recent 30 values of each. Do I need to add a loop within a subquery to limit to 30?
Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

'''

```
DEFINE MACRO userid
  
  '123abc',
  '321cba',
  '987zyx'
  ;

SELECT purchases
FROM random.database
WHERE person = $userid
ORDER BY most_recent_purchases DESC
LIMIT 30 // This is wrong :(
```

'''

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group) can help you

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: it's PostgreSQL

Comment: Thanks @PietroNadalini that was exactly what I was looking for! I was able to get the results I wanted!